# Storing every newline into two zero from a file using C language

Tags: c, file, newline, scanf

*Question Updated with my code.*

I have a file as the format below. Every line contain a integer and a float.

```
12 2.0
11 1.1

3 3.0
```

I want to store the first data in each line into variable A, and second data into variable B.

At the beginning, I use fscanf to do this as below

```
while (1) {
    int exit;

    exit = fscanf(fp, "%d%f", &A, &B);
    if (exit < 2) break;
}
```

If I print the result of A and B, it would be

```
12 2.0
11 1.1
3 3.0
```

But actually I want to store the newline as 2 zero, for example:

```
12 2.0
11 1.1
0 0
3 3.0
```

Some website suggest using fgets/fgetc to read through the newline. But I cannot understand how fgets/fgetc can store integer and float into var A and B.

Thanks for you attention.

Comment: _There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs._

Comment: *But I cannot understand how fgets/fgetc can store integer and float into var A and B.* — Indeed, they can't.  The idea would be to notice when `fgets` has read an empty line, and then store zeroes into A and B by hand.  When it hasn't read an empty line, use `sscanf` to parse it.  Once you have that working, refactor the `sscanf` bit to use `strtod`/`strtol` instead, for better reliability.

Comment: (Pay close attention to the bit in the `fgets` documentation where it explains the difference between what you get for an empty line, and what you get for end of file.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each line, call fgets() with a large enough buffer to hold any line you reasonably expect. The instead of fscanf, call sscanf on the string, with exactly the same parameters. So the programs should now work identically, except it is separating out the IO from the parse.

Now you cat make the parse more complicated. if the line is blank (just whitespace), then the two values are zero, If it is not whitespace, call sscanf and attempt to parse as before. If both fail, you have malformed input, so report an error.

Also, fgets will return null when it runs out of input. So you don't need to use a parse fail to terminate the read any longer.